# Multiple-query log flood in Rails 2.3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using [acts_as_category](https://github.com/funkensturm/acts_as_category) plugin to manage my categories logic. In almost every page of the site the categories and sub-categories tree is shown:

```
<div id="categories_">
  <% Category.roots.each do |category| %>
    <h3><%= category.name %></h3>
    <div>
      <ul class="subcat">
      <% category.children.each do |subcategory| %>
        <li><%= link_to subcategory.name, "/category/#{subcategory.to_param}" %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

It produces a lot of SQL queries shown in the log file, is there a way to **fetch multiple rows in a single query**?

**EDIT:**

I tried rewriting the roots scope in Category model with the same results:

```
named_scope :roots,
            :conditions => ["((hidden IS NULL OR hidden = 0) AND (parent_id IS NULL))"],
            :include => :children
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that the problem is with the plugin, and the author explained here (http://goo.gl/MwRSJ) why it can't be changed. **Any other suggestion for managing my Categories?. I've used acts_as_tree but it seem a bit outdated.** Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the N+1 query problem which is solved by [eager loading associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.10/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

```
<% Category.roots(:include => :children).each do |category| %>
```

Comment: Eager loading will solve the problem, but your example won't work in Rails 2.3

Comment: @Beerlington, thanks, missed that the OP was using 2.3. Updated to reflect that (though I still might be wrong, been a while since I used 2.3)

Comment: Indeed, the plugin does not support the :include parameter, perhaps rewriting it in the model?

Comment: @benoror you might have to put in a feature request to the plugin author(s), or write the change yourself, unfortunately. Rails 3 would also probably not have this sort of issues due to the use of Relations.

Comment: Explanation by the plugin author: https://github.com/funkensturm/acts_as_category/issues/3#issuecomment-981104